# Transaction not rollbacked

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I have a set of operation i would like to be rollbacked if there are an error.

My class

```
public class BSException extends RuntimeException{
...
}

public class saleFacade{

  public update(){

    for (){
      try{
        renewSale();
      }
      catch(BSException){
        logger.error();
      }
    }
  }

  @Transactional
  public renewSale(){
    try{
      findSale(); // read only Transactional
      xxx.renewSpecialSale();
     }
     catch(Exception e){
       logger.error(...);
     }
 }
}


public class xxx(){
  public void renewSpecialSale(){    
    payFee(); //write to db
    if(error){
      throw new BSException();
    }
  }

 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
 public payFee(){
   try{
     ...
   }
   catch(BsException e){
     ...
   }
   catch(Exception e){
     ...
   }
 }
}

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DBConfiguration{
  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
  public BasicDataSource dataSource(){
  ...
  }
}
```

Inn renewSpecialSale error is throw.

In the renewSale method, if there is an error, i would like to rollback.
Right now nothing is rollbacked

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

If you catch the exception before it leaves the method, then there is no way the proxy wrapping the method can know that an exception was thrown.

Either remove the try-catch entirely or rethrow the exception so that the exception can leave the method that you marked @Transactional (and get intercepted by the proxy), and the rollback will take place.

I recommend removing exception-handling from *all* these methods. Set up a central exception handler so that anything thrown from the controllers gets caught and logged, and otherwise let exceptions get thrown.

Make sure each of these classes that does something transactional is annotated separately, if you annotate on the method-level then each method that does something transactional should be annotated. Calling a transactional method from a non-transactional method on the same object doesn't go through the proxy (the proxy intercepts only those calls coming in from outside the object, and only then if that method is marked as transactional) so it isn't part of a transaction (+1 to [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24342474/217324) for pointing this out).

I have no idea what your error flag is doing, it seems odd. Spring services shouldn't have state. If you fix the exception-handling you shouldn't need error flags.

Comment: you mean remove try catch in renewSale method?

Comment: @user3757432: yes. or you could rethrow the exception you catch. (I tend to dislike the catch-log-and-rethrow thing but if it better suits the codebase...)

Comment: i removed it completly and that changed nothing

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your nesting of Method calls and the usage of @Transactional. By default Springs Transaction Management

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional. [Spring Transaction Management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations)

This means, that the call of

```
xxx.payFee()
```

is not surrounded by a transaction when it's called through

```
saleFacade.update() -> saleFacade.renewSale() -> xxx.renewSpecialSale()
```

As far as I got it, you have at least these options

- Mark xxx.renewSpecialSale() as @Transactional
- Mark saleFacade.update() as @Transactional
- Mark both classes xxx and saleFacade @Transactional

Answer (score 0):

remove try catch block from your method and put below line of code

```
 @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

use this line of code insted of

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
```

In above code spring container handle whole transaction management and here if we provide rollback attribute it automatically manage if any kind of exception occur it will rollback your transaction

and make sure that you have entry of transaction in your configuration file as below

```
 <tx:annotation-driven />
```

and also

I hope it will sure help you

Comment: tried to add your line, but nothing seem to be rollbacked

Answer (score 0):

Also you can create your own custom exception class and throw it.

Just throw any `RuntimeException` from a method marked as `@Transactional`.

By default all `RuntimeExceptions` rollback transaction whereas checked exceptions don't. This is an EJB legacy. You can configure this by using `rollbackFor()` and `noRollbackFor()` annotation parameters:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
```

This will rollback transaction after throwing any exception.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = MyCheckedException.class)
public void foo() {
    throw new RuntimeException();    
}
```